# Loading csv into mysql selecting columns

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I am trying to learn how to use efficiently mysql. Now, I want to load into a mysql database a csv containing the bibliography of an author. This is the code I have generating the database and trying to upload the file:

```
USE stephenkingbooks;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stephenkingbooks;
CREATE TABLE stephenkingbooks
(
  `id`              int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `original_title`  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `spanish_title`   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year`            decimal(4) NOT NULL,
  `pages`           decimal(10) NOT NULL,
  `in_collection`   enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `read`            enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',

  PRIMARY KEY     (id)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '../files/unprocessed_sking.csv'
INTO TABLE stephenkingbooks (column1, column2, column4, column3)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The csv file is format like this:

```
Carrie,Carrie,Terror,199,19745,"En 1976, el director de cine Brian de Palma hizo la primera película basada en la novela.7 3"
```

My idea is to load only the two first columns corresponding to the original_title, the second being the spanish title (the same in mysql and the csv) and after the column3 in csv would be the `pages` and the column4 the `year`.

In addition, for the year column, I only want to take the 4 first numbers of the field because I have some of them with a reference that is not part of the year. For example, Carrie was released in 1974 but the csv includes a 5 in the date that I do not want to consider.

My problem is I am not able to obtain what I want without errors in my terminal... any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)
>
> ...
>
> You must also specify a column list if the order of the fields in the
>   input file differs from the order of the columns in the table.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '../files/unprocessed_sking.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE `stephenkingbooks`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    -> (`original_title`, `spanish_title`, @`genre`, @`pages`, @`year`)
    -> SET `year` = LEFT(@`year`, 4), `pages` = @`pages`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    -> `id`,
    -> `original_title`,
    -> `spanish_title`,
    -> `year`,
    -> `pages`,
    -> `in_collection`,
    -> `read`
    -> FROM `stephenkingbooks`;
+----+----------------+---------------+------+-------+---------------+------+
| id | original_title | spanish_title | year | pages | in_collection | read |
+----+----------------+---------------+------+-------+---------------+------+
|  1 | Carrie         | Carrie        | 1974 |   199 | N             | N    |
+----+----------------+---------------+------+-------+---------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Your code raise me the error:

     `ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/home/samuel/github/mysql_tests/files/unprocessed_sking.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)`

I already try to change the owner of the directory /var/lib/mysql to mysql:mysql and it is not working

Comment: @Mastodon: The user account with which MySQL is running must have permissions to access `/home/samuel/github/mysql_tests/files/unprocessed_sking.csv`, however, the error is not found the file.

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much